# .NET's license compiler (LC.EXE) seems to ignore the contents of licenses.licx on one machine, but not on the other. Why?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, activereports, licenses.licx

**Background info:** I've set up a very simple .NET solution in VS2008 that contains just enough code to display an ActiveReports report in a preview window. The ActiveReports component uses the `licenses.licx` mechanism to decide whether it has been properly licensed or not. If it finds no valid license key, it will display a prominent message on the report preview stating, *"This is an evaluation copy, [blah blah blah etc.]."*

**My problem:** I have two computers, both with the same versions of VS2008 and ActiveReports installed. I've got valid licenses for each installation. Now, when I build my solution on one machine, I get a report preview without the evaluation banner message, while on the other, the exact same solution compiles to an application that will display the evaluation message.

**What I've found out so far:** Using [Reflector.NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) I've found out that on the second machine (which displays the evaluation message), the license compiler ([`LC.EXE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/lc-exe-license-compiler)) somehow seems to ignore the ActiveReports license line in `licenses.licx`. But it won't display any error or warning message whatsoever.

**⇒ So, this question remains:** Under what circumstances will `LC.EXE` decide to ignore a line of text from `licenses.licx` when it produces the output `MyApplication.licenses` embedded resource?

---

**P.S.:** The problem is *not* solved by deleting the `licenses.licx` file and then having it recreated by temporarily adding a dummy report to the solution. This trick is [often mentioned](http://weblogs.asp.net/grobinson/archive/2004/04/13/112410.aspx) for similar licensing issues, but it doesn't work here. The `licenses.licx` file contents seems to be valid.

**P.P.S.:** Not entirely sure if this is a Stack Overflow question or one for Super User.

Comment: I found some tips which may prove useful (will try some of them tomorrow): http://keyoti.com/kb/Default.aspx?ToDo=view&questId=76&catId=64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK – I cannot be sure, but I suspect the cause of this problem.

I suspect that `LC.EXE` will probe all controls listed in `licenses.licx` when it compiles that file. If, during that probing, any of the listed controls determines that it is not licensed properly (for whatever reason; e.g. because the license is really missing, or due a corrupt installation), the license compiler won't emit the actual license key to the output resource stream.

---

**Update:** Some weeks later, I still believe this is what happened. As it turned out, the one machine where the licensing failed turned out to have a corrupt installation of ActiveReports. After having run a removal utility, ActiveReports got a fresh install and licensing now works on both machines.